# android wear message to handheld

Tags: android, message, wear-os, receiver

I am using the Android Wearable API to send a simple string message to my handheld device. The message sending is implemented succesfully, the status of the message is SUCCES.

I created a service to receive messages, but it is not working. Every time I send an message from the wearable app the onConnected callback method is calling. Very weird. I show the code:

Service:

```
public class MobileService extends WearableListenerService {
private String TAG = "TAG_SERVICE";
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(new GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks() {
                @Override
                public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onConnected: " + connectionHint);

                }
                @Override
                public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionSuspended: " + cause);
                }
            })
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionFailed: " + result);
                }
            })
            .addApi(Wearable.API)
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(MessageEvent messageEvent) {
    Log.v(TAG, "Message received!");
    super.onMessageReceived(messageEvent);
}
```

}

Logcat of the receiving service, when I send message: (very weird)

```
02-13 18:25:50.652 21490-21490/hu.padar.app.todo D/TAG_SERVICE: onConnected: null
```

Manifest mobile:

```
 <service android:name="hu.padar.app.todo.MobileService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.BIND_LISTENER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
</application>

<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

And the applicationId is the same in both gradle files.

I add some extra information. This is where I send the message:

```
            if (transcriptionNodeId != null) {
            Wearable.MessageApi.sendMessage(mGoogleApiClient, transcriptionNodeId,
                    MESSAGE_PATH, "my message".getBytes()).setResultCallback(
                    new ResultCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResult(Result result) {
                            Log.d(TAG, result.getStatus().toString());
                        }
                    }
            );
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Unable to send message!");
        }
```

This is where I initialize the GoogleApiClient object:

```
 mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                    .addApi(Wearable.API)
                    .build();
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();

            updateNodeId();
```

The updateNodeId() method only puts the correct Node Id to transcirptionNodeId.

Wear dependencies are the following in build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:1.3.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:8.4.0'
}
```

Mobile dependencies are the following in build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
wearApp project(':wear')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
}
```

Comment: Why would you consider that weird? WearableListenerService is not a long-lasting service so it terminates when its job is done and next time, when there is a message, it is instantiated again. For wearable apis, there is no connectionHint so that is why it is null. Why do you need the api client on your mobile anyway? Regarding your manifest, I am not sure what that metadata line is; in the past you needed to add that inside your `<application/>` element but I believe you no longer need that (your manifest has it outside of that element which is incorrect).

Comment: Thank. I dont need api client in mobile, you are right. I removed it. Where I select the node, I only see my phone, so the message goes to to correct device, but the callback isn't working...

Comment: Please show the code on your wear and also more of the log on your mobile.

Comment: I edited the post with the wear code. Btw can u help me with skype+screen sharing? It would be maybe faster?